# static_cast from 'const unsigned char *const *' to 'const char *const *' is not allowed

Tags: c++, static-cast

What I'm experiencing is the refusal of my compiler to cast my unsigned char pointer to a signed char pointer. I got confused for a little while, because I had been using static_cast to convert signedness for the *longest time*.

Then I did a little digging (well, it wasn't very deep. I did a little scooping!) and even though now I understand that the prevention of pointer type casting by `static_cast` is precisely the reason why it's the safer and better way to cast (than the traditional alternatives which may invoke implementation defined behavior or undefined behavior), I'm still not sure what I should actually do for my situation.

What I have here is a call to an OpenGL API function whose signature is

```
void glShaderSource(
    GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar **string, const GLint *length
);
```

I recently changed the file reader API so that instead of returning the data read from a file as a `char *`, I do it now with an `unsigned char *`. This change was not made in error as I feel that an unsigned char is a much better handle to raw data (even though it may well be ASCII data), and indeed `void *` might be even more clear in this regard.

And then of course I'll be passing the address of this pointer in as the third arg to `glShaderSource`.

I reckon that it's safe for me to just do the C-style cast to `GLchar**`, and in fact that is probably the standard answer for this situation. Using `reinterpret_cast` would just be going above and beyond, but admittedly by only a small amount.

But I'd like to maybe find out a bit more about what the thought process is supposed to be in this situation. *Why* is it exactly that I am able to dismiss the signedness of the chars at stake here? Is it simply that since I don't expect to ever write a shader that has the high bit set on any of its characters that means I can cast it?

What if i was facing a situation with signed/unsigned integers, and there really are dire consequences of spurious negative integer values becoming interpreted as large positive values? How can I write code here to try to be "safe" about it?

My instinct is telling me that this is obviously impossible without implementing code that actually goes and observes the data itself instead of passing the pointer, so is there just no way to regain the safety of `static_cast` in this situation, since i'm being forced to work with pointers.

Comment: What is your question? Why you're not allowed to write `static_cast<unsigned char *>(p)` when `p` is a `char *`? You're not just converting from signed to unsigned or vice versa, you're *reinterpreting* what the pointer points to.

Comment: So you are saying that the actual operation i'm performing is a real bona fide reinterpret operation so the use of `reinterpret_cast` is the actual correct thing to do?

Comment: Your last paragraph seems more a gl-question than a C++ question, which is a little odd as no gl-related tags are on this question. Was that intentional?

Comment: No, the question is in no way about what openGL does with the contents

Comment: Well, `reinterpret_cast` will allow the code to compile, I didn't read the wall of text to try and figure out if that's actually what you need :)

Comment: @StevenLu I suspected, but you'll understand my confusion when you said "Is it simply that I don't expect to ever write a shader that has the high bit set?". Noted.

Comment: Yeah sorry about wall of text, i always do that. Basically im trying to figure out when I'm supposed to use which type of cast, but you know what, that question's been answered already! On this very site!

Comment: `I recently changed the file reader API...do it now with an unsigned char *` I would go back to `char *`, because this is what most of the world (including OpenGL) expects. I agree that it is retarded that `char` is signed type (in most cases, although it can be unsigned too, which only brings more confusion).

Comment: @doc, Nahh, I'd rather keep my file reader's logic the way that makes the most sense to me. I think it originally was implemented as `char` because at the time I used it with something expecting `char`. But, like you say, it's dumb to try to reason with and do arithmetic with a signed char type, so I prefer the cleanliness of having it unsigned in my own API. For this type of situation, I'll just reinterpret_cast if i have to... Damn, *I already forgot* the actual real reason I changed it to `unsigned char` today. Must not have been something terribly important.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for the distinction between "digging" and "scooping". There are a *ton* of cast-related questions and answers on this site. An excavator may be needed to find one that truly covers this.

Comment: Yah, well by this point I am well aware that if I didn't at least re-familiarize myself with the basics I'd attract some downvoting. I figure at least the title of my question will help somebody encountering a similar confusing situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `reinterpret_cast` to even convert between `char *` and `unsigned char *`. (with or without const). This is because you are treating bits stored as one type, as the bits for a different type; whereas `static_cast` is for doing value conversions.

As WhozCraig points out, converting between `char **` and `unsigned char **` is actually aliasing one pointer as another pointer type (so, also requiring `reinterpret_cast`).

This could all be a problem in theory, but in terms of practical considerations (IMO), the length of effort you have to go to to support all possibilities is just way too much hassle; for all intents and purposes you can assume that aliasing `char` as `unsigned char` gives the same result as value conversions, and similarly for the two pointer types.

Comment: Correct, but those aren't the types being reinterpreted. There is an additional layer of indirection (which doesn't change the need to reinterpret in the slightest).

Comment: Here's code for my case which compiles `glShaderSource(handle, 1, reinterpret_cast<const GLchar* const*>(&source), sourcelen);`

Comment: So, while it's *technically* implementation-defined behavior, we can be reasonably confident that until I port to a really really different architecture from the ones that we've had for a *long* time, that I can rely on this expected behavior

Comment: @WhozCraig good point. ISTR that `char *` and `unsigned char *` have to have the same size & representation

Comment: @StevenLu: You can bet that such an architecture wouldn't have an OpenGL implementation anyway.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yeah, thats the gamble, that they are the same, that and not phat-fingering the code when you write it and neglect to type the `&` on `source` is Steven's case. The code will happily march into oblivion in that case. I'm always double and triple checking anytime I have to type reinterpret_cast just because of its sledge-hammer approach.

Comment: Well that also gets at the core of my question which is, is there a lesser hammer i can use than the `reinterpret_cast`? I fear not. A C-style cast is worse!

Comment: @StevenLu I honestly don't see a nerf-hammer solution to this, as you definitely have different fundamental pointer types. Using `GLchar` *everywhere* is of course an option, but ... yuck.

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char` are guaranteed to have same storage and alignment requirements, so `reinterpret_cast` should not make harm, but still I think it's better to revert API to `char *` and cast to `unisigned char` if needed.

Comment: @doc surely, but see my first comment (top of this answer), those aren't the types being cast; *pointers-to-pointers* are the ultimate target of the cast, making it f'ugly regardless. I certainly concur on `char` vs `unsigned char` storage and alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the conversion entirely with `static_cast` if you use a `void*` intermediate:

```
unsigned char* src = ...;  // your input
char* srcChar = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(src));
glShaderSource(..., &src, ...);
```

I wouldn't say it's nicer than a `reinterpret_cast`, but at least it shows that a `reinterpret_cast` is not strictly necessary.

Comment: note: if `reinterpret_cast` doesn't work on a particular implementation then this won't work either

Comment: This smacks of sorcery. Rather not use it unless it confers some actual benefit. But, it certainly is a neat trick.

Comment: @StevenLu Well, you were asking for a solution with `static_cast`. ;) While I don't claim that this is pretty, I think it's kind of interesting that `static_cast` is mostly considered safer than `reinterpret_cast`, but in this case, you can do the same thing with a `static_cast` where most people would use a `reinterpret_cast`.